# know when a new thread was created in the AppDomain your application is running after?

Tags: c#, multithreading, appdomain

I would like to know if there is any way to get an event (or something else) that tells you when a new thread was created on your appdomain (C# application)?  The basic idea is that when a new thread is created I need to "initialize" the thread with some settings.

I do not want to go all over my code and do that, as I don't know what future will hold.

Comment: What "settings" are you hoping to initialize the thread with? If the thread is running, it's a little late for that.

Comment: we are setting some environment things for some java loaders....this has to be done on any thread (and already done manually now) before you can use it

Comment: So not so much thread settings but environment settings that subsequent operations performed by the thread will use. Sounds like these threads should be managed by a class that performs the setup, if I'm understanding you.

Answer (score 1):

Create a thread static variable, and initialize anything you need in the constructor.

```
class ThreadEnvironmentSettings
{
    [ThreadStatic]
    public static readonly ThreadEnvironmentSettings Settings = 
         new ThreadEnvironmentSettings();

    public ThreadEnvironmentSettings()
    {
        SetupJavaEnvironment();
    }

    public void EnsureSetup(){
        // Doesn't do anything but required to 'touch' the thread variable
    }
}
```

Then before calling any methods that require an established environment:

```
ThreadEnvironmentSettigns.Settings.EnsureSetup();
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that java loaders execute on the other process. And .NET code just specifies correct arguments for the command line - then you can use environment variables for the whole process.

Environment variables are global to the whole process (that is all threads will have access to them even newly created ones). Here's [how](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z46c489x.aspx) to set a variable in C#.